# Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined

Tags: visualforce, javascript, d3

While trying to execute, i'm getting an error saying d3 is not defined . Referring to the link : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885705  to create bar chart. Appreciate the help.

```
<apex:page sidebar="true" showHeader="true"> 
   <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery1)}"/>    
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1, 1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(formatPercent);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });

  d3.select("input").on("change", change);

  var sortTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    d3.select("input").property("checked", true).each(change);
  }, 2000);

  function change() {
    clearTimeout(sortTimeout);

    // Copy-on-write since tweens are evaluated after a delay.
    var x0 = x.domain(data.sort(this.checked
        ? function(a, b) { return b.frequency - a.frequency; }
        : function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.letter, b.letter); })
        .map(function(d) { return d.letter; }))
        .copy();

    var transition = svg.transition().duration(750),
        delay = function(d, i) { return i * 50; };

    transition.selectAll(".bar")
        .delay(delay)
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x0(d.letter); });

    transition.select(".x.axis")
        .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("g")
        .delay(delay);
  }
});

</script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing this library, it looks like a required component for the code you're using: http://d3js.org/

Comment: Its working fine now . But the graph is showing below the page area . Meaning i want to display it on the white area o the page .

Comment: That's a different issue, maybe create a new question with screenshots etc.

Comment: @user2031491 +1 for DavinC's suggestion. This `d3.select("body").append("svg")` is making the graph area an immediate child of the HTML body. You can add other HTML (or Visualforce) elements to the page and make your graph a child of whichever gives you the right layout. Try that and if you can't make it work post another question. And you should accept the current answer as it does answer the original question.